# How do I grab the username and password from my ArrayList so that I can verify a login?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

```
package appLogin;

public class Account {

    String user;
    String pass;
    
    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.user = username;
        this.pass = password;
        
        
    }
    
    
}
public static void logIn() {
        String username;
        String password;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter your username please ");
            username = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter your password please ");
            password = scanner.nextLine();

            boolean loggedIn = false;
            for(Account acc : accounts) {
                if (acc.user.equals(username) && acc.pass.equals(password)) {
                    loggedIn = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (loggedIn) {
                System.out.print("You have been logged into your account");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("You have typed in an incorrect username or password, please try again");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get a user registered and their details will be parsed properly but I can't for the life of me get it to work as a whole system and allow me to login with that user or check all the users registered.

I tried to create a program that would ask the user to register a user (making sure that their username and password were the correct length) and then allowing them to login with the same username and password. Lastly I wanted to be able to display all the usernames that have registered using an Arraylist (accounts).

Edit, I have now fixed this program and shown my Account file so you guys can figure it out too.

Comment: Does class Account have a getter for username and password?...

Comment: My Account class has a function for this.user and this.pass and I'm trying to get that to work

Answer (score 0):

Login: Iterate over `accounts`, put the subject element in `Account`:
`Account acc = accounts.get(i);`. Check `acc.username` for input username and then for password.
Display Users: Iterate like above and just `System.out.println(acc.username);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming class `Account` had both `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` getters that return a String, you'd do something like:

```
String username;
String password;

System.out.println("Enter your username please ");
username = input.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter your password please ");
password = input.nextLine();

boolean loggedIn = false;
for(Account acc : accounts) {
  if (acc.getUsername().equals(username) && acc.getPassword().equals(password)) {
    loggedIn = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (loggedIn) {
  System.out.print("You have been logged into your account");
}
else {
    System.out.print("You have typed in an incorrect username or password, please try again");
}
```

For your `Account` class, you should never use the default access modifier for fields (`user` and `pass`). This means that those values can be freely changed without any validation. They should be `private` and then you should provide "getters" for them to make them read-only. Making them `private` means they cannot be seen from outside the class. If you provide "setters" for them then you can guarantee that they don't get changed without you validating the new values first, or performing other necessary actions upon a change:

```
public class Account {

    private String user;
    private String pass;
    
    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.user = username;
        this.pass = password;                        
    }
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return pass;
    }

}
```

Comment: this worked amazingly well thank you